# How to do Localization of Razor Pages

Tags: localization, razor-pages

I wasted a lot of time sifting through incomplete explanations of how to localize Razor Pages, often discovering that answers were about MVC.  So let me save you all that time, and just give you the simple steps that worked for me.  I don't pretend to know the details of why anything is needed, just that it worked.

Answer (score 7):

1. Add the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization nuGet package to the project.
2. To _ViewImports.cshtml, add:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

3. In Startup.cs, change

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

to

```
services.AddLocalization( options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources" );
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddViewLocalization();
```

4. Add the supported languages in Startup.cs, by inserting something like the following before app.UseHttpsRedirection():

```
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo( "en-US" ),
    new CultureInfo( "fr" )
};
var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture( "en-US" ),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
app.UseRequestLocalization( options );
```

5. Add localization to your pages, like:

```
<h2>@Localizer["Hello"]</h2>
```

6. To the web project, add a folder named Resources, with a subdirectory named Pages.  In Resources/Pages, add resource files matching the names of the pages to localize.  For example, Index.fr.resx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <data name="Hello" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Bonjour</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

7. Test your localization by adding a query string, such as during debugging changing your URL to https://localhost:5001/?culture=fr

Comment: Works great; however, I'd prefer a single resx file for each language. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-7.0#shared-resources appears to refer to such a scenario. Anyone knowing how to implement this?

Comment: @mortenma71 - please see my answer. I have been doing this for years in both MVC and Razor pages.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar with Razor pages and I have one file for each language that contains all the resource strings/images, i.e. my files are named something like

```
Res.resx
Res.da.resx
Res.es.resx
```

**program.cs** looks like this:

```cs
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");    
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        /* Enable support for localized DataAnnotations validation 
           messages. 
           NB: this works in .NET 7.0
         */
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
     {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (_, factory) =>
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(Res).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
                return factory.Create(nameof(Res), assemblyName.Name!);
        };
     });
     ...
```

**Folder structure**:

[image: folder structure with Resource file]

**Properties of the .resx**:

It is important to add the string `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` to the `Custom Tool property` of only the main resource file, i.e. `Res.resx` to have Visual Studio generate the `Res.Designer.cs` class.

[image: Properties of the resx]

**Usage**:

I don't use `@Localizer["PrivacyPolicy"]` but instead `@Res.PrivacyPolicy`. See example below:

[image]